# Auto link urls in PHP that don't have quotes around them (Code modify needed)

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, preg-replace, autolink

OK, I've been using the following code to find any URLS in the text that I enter, but some things like YouTube code or whatnot have links in them and it finds those as well.  I would like to have this code modified so that it ignores quotes around the links that are already a part of something.

`public function auto_link_text($text) {

```
    $pattern  = '#\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))#';
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, array($this, 'auto_link_text_callback'), $text);

}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just excludes links preceded by a quotation mark

```
/(?<=[^"]|^)(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/
```

Comment: Awesome!  It works perfectly!  I removed the |ftp|file part of it to keep it secure.  Thank you.  =)